# Is it possible to have a column chart on top of a line chart with the zero Y value for each column being the Y value of the line chart?

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to have the line chart set the Y axis values for scaling.  It's showing cash balance on the Y axis and time on the X axis.  That's simple.  Now I want to add columns that would show the net income for that date.  These columns are laid out on top of the line chart with the zero for the column being wherever the line is for that X value and then going up if positive or going down if negative.  The column values can't be on the same Yaxis as the line chart because they are much smaller values (being a single month summary instead of a continuous cash balance.  I could hide the second y axis, but each column starts from a different zero point, so while the scale would have the same magnitude for all the columns, they'd all have different zero positions on that axis.

Is the kind of chart highcharts can support?  Any pointers how?

thanks!

Comment: Why not use whisker plots (error bars) but make the upper/lower bounds be the net gain/loss?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need one of this chart, http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes or this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Comment: Well, in general, some mockup would be really helpful, but @Kaha is right - it should be possible, by combining both of examples (if we understand you properly).

Comment: As noted, using a column range series and a line series should accomplish this.  However, if you're going to make your columns use a different y axis with a different scale, the chart will be entirely pointless and will simply distort the data.  You best bet is to make this two separate charts.  Combining them into one offers no actual benefit, and significant decrease of clarity.

Comment: In addition, even if the bar and line series used the same y axis, by placing the bars at uneven base lines, you remove the one thing that a bar chart does - allow users to compare the length of the bars from a common baseline.  Two charts, arranged vertically, will eliminate any problems.